# Gradle doesn't see gradle.properties from GRADLE_USER_HOME

Tags: java, spring, gradle, gradle.properties

**CAUTION**: I've read all topics with the same error but didn't found the way to fix

I've installed gradle locally on my windows PC and I try to run execute `gradle clean` command

```
C:\work\onsolve\acadia>gradle clean
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\work\****\build.gradle' line: 7

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'a****a'.
> Could not get unknown property 'prop1' for Credentials [username: null] of type org.gradle.internal.credentials.DefaultPasswordCredentials_Decorated.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

But if I copy `gradle.properties` from **GRADLE_USER_HOME**(C:\Users***.gradle) to the project folder - error disappears.

Some additional info from cmd:

```
C:\work\onsolve\acadia>gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.9
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-05-07 07:28:53 UTC
Revision:     afe2e24ababc7b0213ccffff44970aa18035fc0e

Kotlin:       1.4.20
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_291 (Oracle Corporation 25.291-b10)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64


C:\work\***\***>set GRADLE_USER_HOME
GRADLE_USER_HOME=C:\Users\***\.gradle
```

What have I missed ?

**P.S.**

snippet from **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://artifactory.***.****.com/artifactory/maven" 
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

**gradle.properties** :

```
org.gradle.daemon=false
artifactory_user=****
artifactory_password=****
```

Comment: could you add the snippet of how you read that prop1, something like -> https://discuss.gradle.org/t/read-a-property-from-gradle-properties/27148/2

Comment: where are you using gradle?android  project?

Comment: @Gabriel Aguiar - legacy java spring project

Comment: @gstackoverflow show me gradle.properties

Comment: @sschrass  added requested information

Comment: @Gabriel Aguiar please read topic update

Comment: you hae a gradle-wrapper.properties?

Comment: @Gabriel Aguiar yes I have but I used `gradle clean` but not `gradlew clean`

Comment: @Gabriel Aguiar I don't have `local.properties`

Comment: @gstackoverflow add this to your gradle.properties and restart your IDE gradle.user.home=C:/Users/you user/.gradle  and change system variable path to C:/Users/you user/.gradle

Comment: @Gabriel Aguiar could you please explain in details what should I do. From my point of view all env variabes are set correctly

Comment: @gstackoverflow change GRADLE_USER_HOME path to C:/Users/you user/.gradle

Comment: @gstackoverflow and add gradle.user.home=C:/Users/you user/.gradle to gradle.properties file

Comment: @Gabriel Aguiar GRADLE_USER_HOME is set properly according my initial post.  Please reread.

But this phrase is not clear **and add gradle.user.home=C:/Users/you user/.gradle to gradle.properties file**
Sounds too complex. My teammates doesn't have it and it works for them properly

Comment: What `gradle clean --debug` produces? Does `Gradle user home:` value appears?

Comment: @LMC I see line 
2021-07-22T11:19:56.963+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] Setting project property: env.GRADLE_USER_HOME -> C:\Users\myusername\.gradle

Comment: @LMC 
Also I see:
`2021-07-22T11:31:11.064+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] Looking for project properties from: C:\work\***\gradle.properties
2021-07-22T11:31:11.064+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] project property file does not exists. We continue!
`

Comment: `2021-07-22T11:31:11.064+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] Looking for project properties from: C:\work\***\c***\gradle.properties
2021-07-22T11:31:11.064+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] project property file does not exists. We continue!`

Comment: `2021-07-22T11:31:11.064+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] Looking for project properties from: C:\work***\***-common\gradle.properties
2021-07-22T11:31:11.064+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] project property file does not exists. We continue!
202`

Comment: wow! It doesn't find the file even being there. What if you try in a clean project? I mean, no previous gradle activity there before, with a different user if possible. Should work or, there's a phantom in your project lol

Comment: @LMC could you please provide detailed steps what to do ? I didn't get what should I do

Comment: I see two directories inside projects (Linux), `gradle` and `.gradle`. I say, copy your whole project, delete those directories there and run gradle.

Comment: 1. What do you get if you run the command “dir %GRADLE_USER_HOME%” , does it show the contents of your .gradle folder with gradle.properties file? 2. Does the .gradle folder have correct access rights? (You can try running the gradle command in a CMD terminal started in Administration mode.) 3. Does your .properties file use correct line endings e.g. CRLF or LF and does the last character in your properties end with CRLF or LF. (I have encountered once that a properties file could not be loaded into a java program running on a linux os because it ended with  CRLF instead of LF.)

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle.kts

```
repositories {
    maven("url") {
        credentials {
            username = rootProject.properties["user"].toString()
            password = rootProject.properties["password"].toString()
        }
    }
    maven("url2")
    mavenLocal()
}
```

Comment: I don't understand you answer. You use Kotlin. I use Java. Where is my mistake ?

Comment: This script accesses the rootProject and its properties. These should also include the values from {GRADLE_HOME}/.gradle/gradle.properties.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was because `org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true`in gradle.properties.
When I removed this line it started to work.